# having a storyboard in visual studio like in Xcode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I would like to know if any of you have found a way to have a storyboard element like the one there is in XCode when you develop for an IOS application? But for Visual Studio when you develop for Windows Phone or Store apps? Does visual studio do this? Do i need to add a feature to Visual Studio to do this? or is it only in XCode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen nothing like Xcode's storyboard in Visual Studio.

Blend for Visual Studio has a lot of visual tools.  The Objects and Timeline pane might be the closest in functionality:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/dd565842.aspx